# Three.js console.log specific points via getPoints() on an ellipsecurve() for later use

Tags: three.js

I need to extract specific points out of a shape, an ellipse curve in this case, so that I can use them to place individual particles later on in my code but I don't understand three.js, or javascript for that matter, to understand what I'm doing wrong here.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve( .35, .15, .35, .23, 150, 450, false, 0 );
var points = curve.getPoints( 8 );
console.log(points.x[5]);
console.log(points.y[5]);
```

Comment: Maybe, it's better to do it this way: `points[5].x`, `points[5].y`.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you @prisoner849, that's what I needed to get access to these points.